# Void Linux won't start past command line anymore after editing pam.d files

Tags: boot, pam, display-manager

Asking for help as a last resort before just fully reinstalling. I'm running Void Linux and just installed it yesterday on my new laptop, however I can no longer boot.

This is what I did:

- First i did an update using

  ```shell
  sudo xbps-isntall -Su
  ```
- Then I was setting up the fingerprint scanner so installed the `fprintd` package.
- I also installed `brightnessctl` for my keyboard backlight and set it up with

  ```shell
  brightnessctl --device='tpacpi::kbd_backlight' set 2
  ```
- Then I edited `/etc/pam.d/system-local-login` and added

  ```
  auth      sufficient pam_fprintd.so
  ```

  to it. I also added that line to `sudo` because I thought fingerprint for `sudo` would be neat.

I have this weird problem where if I move my mouse into the top right corner of my screen it goes black with a blinking cursor. It used to do this on the top left corner but removing the Void Linux app list thing fixed it.

Not realizing it happened in the other corner I moved the cursor and the screen went black. Now after rebooting I get

```
void 6.6.9_1 (void (tty1)

void login: [     7.111481] Bluetooth: hci0: malformed msft vendor event: 0x02
[    7.313476] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: wrt: invalid buffer destination
[    7.549431] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: wrt: invalid buffer destination
```

I am able to login and use the terminal but the screen is black.

I have since removed the lines from the `pam.d` files that I changed, I also tried booting from an older kernel that had worked before but it's the same. Since `lightdm` wasn't starting I thought this was a display manager issue and it used to say

```
elogind process already running pid 902
```

since some threads said `elogind` may cause the issue so I removed it from `runit/sv/services` (I think that's the directory - I forgot, but it no longer has the message about it).

I have no clue what the issue is since I removed the changes I made. Does anyone have any ideas before I just reinstall Void Linux?